# Deferred binding to instance using Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have this in my module:

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(Authenticator.class).toInstance(KerberosAuthenticator.create());
}
```

And the reason for binding to instance here is because Kerberos authentication needs a bit of initialization like so:

```
    public static KerberosAuthenticator create() {
    KerberosAuthenticator auth = new KerberosAuthenticator();
    auth.start();
    return auth;
}
```

This works. I particularly like the fact that it works without noise like factories and providers... Can I somehow defer creating this instance. Obviously the create() method is called at the time I am configuring the binding. In this case the creation is not expensive, but in other cases it may be, or, perhaps, not even needed...  I am, somehow, missing it in the Guice docs...
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Provider,

bind(Authenticator.class)
        .toProvider(AuthenticatorProvider.class)

check this

https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProviderBindings

Comment: Hm, I missed it?... I guess I missed it... This is the answer. Makes it very clean at the point of injection. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write a [provider method](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods):

```
@Provides
Authenticator provideAuthenticator() {
  KerberosAuthenticator auth = new KerberosAuthenticator();
  auth.start();
  return auth;
}
```

This meets your requirement of lazyness because (from the page):

> Whenever the injector needs an instance of that type, it will invoke the method.

Comment: @Provides is not same as Provider. This is not the right answer.

Comment: @KitKarson It's as good as the other answer. See https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods

Comment: I saw that already. The OP looks for lazy injection. `@Provides` does not do that. Provider is the right way to do it. `@Provides` would be helpful when you need to do something with the object before injection. But it is not lazy.

Comment: @KitKarson The documentation I linked states: "Whenever the injector needs an instance of that type, it will invoke the method." That's the definition of "lazy"